# react router v4 default page(not found page)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is common purpose, directing unmatch request to notfound page.

making this with react-router v4 looks like previous versions and I expect this 
sample works below. Links work fine but I expect NotFound component called only unknown url requested; but its always there.

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'


class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/user">User</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
        <Route path="*" component={Notfound}/>
      </div>
  </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

its since `path="*"` represent all request and notfound component always there but how can I say hide this component for valid url path?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

React Router's [*No Match* documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) covers this. You need to import the `<Switch>` component, then you can remove the `path` attribute altogether.

> A `<Switch>` renders the first child `<Route>` that matches. A `<Route>` with no path always matches

This is the example that uses:

```html
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match"/>
      <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
      <Route component={NoMatch}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

So in your case, you'd simply drop the `path="*"` and introduce the `<Switch>`:

```html
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
  <Route component={Notfound} />
</Switch>
```

Remember to include `Switch` to your `import` statement at the top.

Comment: Works like charm, thx! iǘe just found an awesome and useful post just for append more about react-routes v4 - https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: But then how to I choose the location path for my 404 ?

Answer (score 6):

this is my solution with two components.

```html
const NotFound = () => <div>Not found</div>

const NotFoundRedirect = () => <Redirect to='/not-found' />

//root component
<Switch>
 <Route path='/users' component={UsersPages} />
 <Route path='/not-found' component={NotFound} />
 <Route component={NotFoundRedirect} />
</Switch>

//UsersPages component
<Switch>
 <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
 <Route path='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
 <Route component={NotFoundRedirect} />
</Switch>
```

That work perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: How do you rewrite the 404 location path

Comment: Is simple wherever you have a switch at the end put a <Route component={NotFoundRedirect} /> and allways you go to have a 404 redirect. Thank's

Answer (score 3):

This method works perfectly, it allows to make a redirect if the url does not exist or if it is false

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/sorties-scolaires" component={SortiesScolaires} />
        <Route path="/voyages-entreprise" component={VoyagesEntreprise} />
        <Route path="*">
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the accept solution does provide the answer, but it wouldn't work when you have nested Routes

For instance, if the `Home` component has nested Routes like `/home`, `/dashboard` and if the visited url is `/db`, it would show a `NotFound` component only within the Route section, but not the page as a whole.

To avoid this, you can go along with a very simple tweak of using a component and a Provider

```
const NoMatch = (props) => (
    <Redirect to={{state: {noMatch: true}}} />
)

const ProviderHOC = (NotFoundRoute) => {
    const RouteProvider = (props) => {
        if(props.location && props.location.state && props.location.noMatch) {
           return  <NotFoundRoute {...props} />
        }
        return props.children;
    }
    return withRouter(RouteProvider)

}

export default ProviderHOC;
```

And then you can use it like

```
const RouteManager  = ProviderHOC(NotFoundComponent);

<Router>
  <RouteManager>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match"/>
      <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
      <NoMatch />
    </Switch>
  </RouteManager>
</Router>
```

and within Home component

```
render() {
    return (
         <Switch>
               <Route path="/home" component={NewHome} />
               <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
               <NoMatch />
         </Switch>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Router v6**

I know it was a question for Router v4, but since there is **v6** out, to redirect and navigate to one of our chosen routes, we can use `<Navigate>` component from React Router.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Now we can declare below our route configuration the case for empty routes, like this:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate to="/users" />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Live Demo: [Redirect Default or 404 Routes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/redirect-routes-with-react-router)

Answer (score -2):

It does not work for me, particularly one is using this [config](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config)

So, I have to check the path in the render function of Homepage component. Something like this:

```js
render(){
const {match, location, history} = this.props;
if (location.pathname === '/'){
return (<div>Home</div>)
}else{
return null
}
}
```

Comment: OP is asking about a route that is not found or possible a malformed url, not the root url.