# history.push(path) is not working in react-router-dom v4, with redux while redirecting to 404

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to redirect user to `not-found` url when unknown url is given,

and I am using `history.push('not-found')` for same,

but it doesn't work, inside `ComponentwillReceiveProps()`.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.profile.profile === null && 
     this.props.profile.loading) {
      this.props.history.push("/not-found");
    }
  }
```

In `App.js`, using `BrowserRouter as Router`,
I am rendering component `NotFound`, as

But Problem is `{NotFound}` is shown to only path `/not-found`, not for other incomplete paths,

How can I show NotFound Component for other unspecified routes?

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]
[github-project-link](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks/tree/03b73b539e4af1e994ab05be78144971654a0308)

`app.js` is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import store from "./store";

import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "./actions/authActions";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import Landing from "./components/layout/Landing";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import CreateProfile from "./components/create-profile/CreateProfile";
import EditProfile from "./components/edit-profile/EditProfile";
import AddExperience from "./components/add-credentials/AddExperience";
import AddEducation from "./components/add-credentials/AddEducation";
import Profiles from "./components/profiles/Profiles";
import Profile from "./components/profile/Profile";

import PrivateRoute from "./components/common/PrivateRoute";
import NotFound from "./components/not-found/NotFound";

import "./App.css";
import { clearCurrentProfile } from "./actions/profileActions";

// check if token is stored in localstorage, if user has logged in.

if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // if token exitst, then set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);

  // now decode token and get user-info, expiry-date of token
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);

  // set user and user is now authenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  // check for expired date of token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // exp should be greater to keep alive login
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Logout user and clear it's profile
    store.dispatch(clearCurrentProfile());
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <div className="container">
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
              <Route exact path="/profile/:handle" component={Profile} />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/create-profile"
                  component={CreateProfile}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-profile"
                  component={EditProfile}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-experience"
                  component={AddExperience}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-education"
                  component={AddEducation}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Route exact path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

in `connect-geeks/frontend/src/components/profile/Profile.js` file,

I am using method `history.push(path)`,

also `withRouter` didn't worked, on wrapping `connect()` in it.

**edit 1:**

after adding Route with path="*" as,

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
     <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

it didn't worked as

[image: screenshot]

I tried [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929472/react-router-v4-default-pagenot-found-page?noredirect=1&lq=1), but i couldn't apply it for both private and public routes.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929472/react-router-v4-default-pagenot-found-page/52261444#52261444 on how to implement a 404 page interaction with react-router v4

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `Route` to your router, with the `path="*"`, that will catch all the unmapped routes.

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
```

I recommend you to read this: [React-Router v4 - Handling 404 pages](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-handling-404-pages/)

Comment: thanks, it worked for unspecified routes but it is appearing for all other routes, as this https://imgur.com/a/nKQF5pT   and whole code is here https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/connect-geeks/commits/master.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh, try to add a `path="*"` to the component `Route`

Comment: it didn't worked after adding `path="*"`  to <Route/>, same problem persists.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh The problem is that you've created another `<Switch>` just to the `not-found`, then, it will be always rendered. Try to let it along with the other routes