# React Router redirect when url isn't correct

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can you help me!

I'm stuck with url pameters. When I type http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch/sdf , then I got redirected. It's great, that's what I want. But when http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch111/ , nothing is happening.

Is it possible to get redirected when url isn't correct?

I've tried to enter http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch1 , but I stay on WillMatch, but I want to get NoMatch if url isn't correct

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/willmatch">Will Match</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/will-not-match">Will Not Match</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/also/will/not/match">Also Will Not Match</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/:id" component={WillMatch} />
            {/* <Route component={NoMatch} /> */}
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}

function WillMatch({ match }) {
  return <h1>{match.params.id}</h1>
}

function NoMatch() {
  return <h1>NoMatch}</h1>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react router v4 default page(not found page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929472/react-router-v4-default-pagenot-found-page)

Comment: nah, they don't talk about url parameters

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's thinks maybe it thinks `willmatch` is `:id`.  I have one working like:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={WillMatch} />
    <Route path="/notfound" exact component={NoMatch} />
    <Redirect to="/notfound" />
</Switch>
```

You could also try:

```
    <Route path="/thing/:id" component={WillMatch} />
```

A similar example is provided here:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

> A `<Switch>` renders the first child `<Route>` that matches. A `<Route>` with no path always matches

Comment: I've tried to enter http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch1 , but I stay on WillMatch, but I want to get NoMatch if url isn't correct

Comment: Answer updated.  In the one I have working, I removed `exact` from the `:id` route.

Comment: it doesn't work. have you tried your own code? it's not a similar example.

when this url  http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch isn't correct, for example

http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch1
http://localhost:3000/#/willmatsfdch
http://localhost:3000/#/wi12llmatch

i want to get redirected to the NoMatch.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<Route exact strict path="/:id" component={WillMatch} />`

`/:id` is a placeholder and it matches everything. Without `strict` it matches `/whatever` and `/whatever/`. With `strict` it matches only `/whatever`.

You either need to list all valid paths or check `props.match.params.id` inside `WillMatch` component and redirect if it is not valid.

Comment: I've tried to enter http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch1 , but I stay on WillMatch, but I want to get NoMatch if url isn't correct

Comment: Thanks! Something like that?

function WillMatch({ match }) {
  if (match.params.id == 'willmatch') {
    return <h1>{match.params.id}</h1>
  } else {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
}

I'm not good at react syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place something like this at the bottom of your Routes, make sure it's at the bottom or else it will match every route. It will redirect if the route isnt found among the rest!

Comment: I've tried to enter http://localhost:3000/#/willmatch1 , but I stay on WillMatch, but I want to get NoMatch if url isn't correct