# React Router v5 - nesting routes without exact prop

Tags: reactjs

My App.tsx:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
  <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Dashboard.tsx component:

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={DashboardIndex} />
  <Route path={`${path}/users`} component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

The actual problem lies in the "/dashboard" nested routes. Since i'm not using an `exact` prop on it, it would match anything, like "/dashboard/blablabla" though this route doesn't exist in my app. Only "/dashboard/users" does exist. How to deal with non existent routes, when `exact` is not being used?

**UPDATE**

Ended up using this approach:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={DashboardIndex} />
  <Route path={`${path}/users`} component={Users} />
  <Route path={`${path}/*`} component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Also if you want to completely redirect to another page, just use `<Redirect to="/path" />`:

```
<Route path={`${path}/*`}>
  <Redirect to="/path" />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scenarios like this the best way is to have a 404 page which you render for non existing Routes

You can change your code to something similar like

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={DashboardIndex} />
  <Route path={`${path}/users`} component={Users} />
  <NotFoundRoute />
</Switch>
```

Please refer [**this SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929472/react-router-v4-default-pagenot-found-page/52261444#52261444) to check implementation of not found route.

Comment: With this "Declarative" way, is it ok to put a `<NotFoundRoute />` everywhere in a nested structure? For example, i have a not found route in App.tsx, then inside a dashboard, then if i would have "/cars" there would i declare not found route either? Also what if `<Route path={`${path}/users`} component={Users} />` would have nested routes either? I should handle not found cases inside `Users` component?

Comment: You can have a NotFoundRoute anywhere in the nested structure. The only thing you need to keep in mind is that this NotFoundRoute must always be inside a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this before, may this helps

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={DashboardIndex} />
  <Route path={`${path}/users`} component={Users} />
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch } />
</Switch>
```

No match component

```
function NoMatch() {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```